# What type of LCD display is this?

Tags: lcd

I have an old alarm clock where the LCD broke down (powered by 2xAA batteries)

The LCD is transparent, and can only show 4 7-segment characters, plus some indications such as dividing ':', alarm on etc.

[image: type of display]

Upon opening I found that the LCD screen is attached to the PCB by a very flimsy, thin piece of tape, with some sort of conductive black lines on it. They come off very easily.

[image: internals of the alarm clock]
[image]

I measure 1.0 volt wrt to Ground on all 16 pins going to the LCD. When pressing a button (to change something on the screen), I measure some pins jumping up/down to 0.9 or 1.1V momentarily.

1. What kind of LCD is this?
2. How is it driven, how is it controlled?

If possible, as some hobby-hacking I would like to reuse the PCB and drive some other LCD screen with it (reusing this LCD is obviously not an option, as the tape is gone), so any info on the type, signals, pin out would be great.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's just a passive LCD, a bare glass with connections to drive the segments. Based on wire count it has a few common and a few segment wires so it's multiplexed instead of having one common and one wire per each segnent that can be driven
2. It is driven with few volts of AC between common wire and segment wire. Updated one common at a time for multiple segments per single common. There are a lot of resources how to drive a bare LCD glass, multiplexed or not.

The problem is, this can be a custom LCD glass so the segments and how they are divided into separate commons may be arranged in any order.

It is unlikely that you will find another bare LCD glass with the same segment and common arrangement, but feel free to reverse-engineer the pinout of the glass and figure out the segment mapping, and try if you find another glass with the same matrix, even if the order of the pins is different.

You can drive a segment on by applying few volts of AC square wave to common and segment terminal. Square wave frequency can likely be from 10s of Hz to few hundred Hz. DC voltage will damage an LCD in the long run, but for quick testing it might not matter if the square wave has a DC offset.